# Fundamental understanding of reactive lists

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I wrote a little standard application in R that is running pretty fine.
It scans the *.png files in a folder and extracts some statistics on pixel granularity and colours.

Now it is my idea to transfer this to shiny. Although I once wrote some smaller Shiny-Apps, i never used reactivity intensely.

The basic idea of the here presented code is:

- to choose png files from a folder
- show the number of chosen images
- initiate some calculations on the chosen files after clicking a button
- displaying the extracted parameters

I now have critical problems with the basic design of the reactive variables, obviously as my construct in mind is not suitable.

Is there someone who could advise me the basic outline of the shiny construct?

I tried to reduce the code to the bare minimum. I hope one can follow my thoughts.

```
library (shiny)



options (shiny.maxRequestSize = 250 * 1024^2)
# increase maximum data upload to 250MB


const_Number_of_Variables = 5
# just to keep the number of extracted parameters 
# up to date when new parameters will be included



ui <- fluidPage(
# just a simple UI with some basic elements
        fileInput ("ui_IMGfiles", 
                  "Choose PNG files",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c ("image/png",
                              ".png")
        ),
    
        tag$hr,
 
        tableOutput ("ui_IMGfilelistcontents"),
        
        tag$hr,
        
        textOutput ("imagecount"),
        
        tag$hr,
        
        actionButton ("ui_btn_CalcFeatures", "Calculate image features", class = "btn-warn"),
        
        tag$hr,
        
        tableOutput('IMG_featuretable')
  )







IMG_filelist <- reactiveValues (data = NULL)
IMG_features <- reactiveValues (val1 = NULL, val2 = NULL, val3 = NULL, val4= NULL, val5 = NULL, val6 = NULL)
IMG_data     <- reactiveValues (data = NULL)




server <- function(input, output) {
  

  observeEvent (input$ui_IMGfiles, {
    # input$ui_IMGfiles will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads files, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    IMG_filelist$data <- input$ui_IMGfiles
  })

  
    
  output$ui_IMGfilelistcontents <- renderTable({
    # if file list is not initialised, return NULL
    if (is.null (IMG_filelist$data () ))
      return(NULL)
    
    #finally display the list of images
    IMG_filelist$data ()
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  output$imagecount <- renderText({ 
    # whenever the file list changes, identify 
  # the number of elements from the length of list entries
    paste0 ("# of files: ", length (IMG_filelist$data () ))
    }
  )
  
  
  
  
   IMG_data <- observeEvent (input$ui_btn_CalcFeatures, {
      # check whether some images are loaded
      if (is.null (IMG_filelist)) {IMG_data = NULL}
      IMG_files_count = length (IMG_filelist)
    
      # prepare the feature list that will be 
      # overwritten every time the button is pressed
      IMG_data$data = matrix (NaN, nrow = 1, ncol = const_Number_of_Variables)
    
      for (i in 1:IMG_files_count) {
          # now read the i'th image from the list and pass it to the evaluation function
          aSourceImage  = readPNG (IMG_filelist$data [i]$datapath, native = FALSE, info = TRUE)
          
          # extract the desired parameters and attach them to the list
          IMG_data$data = rbind ( c ("val1", "Val2", "val3", "Val4", "etc"),
                                  #fn_ExtractTileInformation (aSourceImage, aFileFullPath, aFileName, 128),
                                  IMG_data$data ())
      }
  })  

   
   
   
  output$IMG_featuretable <- renderDataTable (img_data$data ())
   
}

shinyApp (ui, server)
```

Comment: If you haven't seen them yet, check out the [vidoes from the shiny developer conference](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/shiny-dev-con-2016/) especially the talks by Joe Cheng. Otherwise please try to edit your question to ask a more specific programming question. What exactly is the problem with what you've written. What needs to change? Also it would be nice to use an example that doesn't rely on having a folder full pf PNG files lying around so we can run and test it ourselves.

Comment: Nevertheless a single png file would also work fine. There is no need to have a bunch of them.

Comment: Yes, i know the videos. But that what i tried is different from the examples. My idea of using reactivity seems different from that what finally works.